# $\vec{\nabla}^2 \frac{1}{r} =\frac{1}{r^4}$ or $\vec{\nabla}^2 \frac{1}{r} =0$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, physics

ChatGPT-Calculation:

$$\vec{\nabla}^2 \frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{1}{r} \right) = \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r \cdot \frac{-1}{r^2} \right) = \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( \frac{-1}{r} \right) = \frac{1}{r^2} \left( \frac{1}{r^2} \right) = \frac{1}{r^4}$$

My Calculation:
$$\vec{\nabla}^2 \frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{1}{r} \right) = \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^2 \cdot \frac{-1}{r^2} \right) = \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( -1 \right) = \frac{1}{r^2} \left(0 \right) = 0$$

Did I make a mistake in the calculation?

Comment: Recheck your work, recheck the ChatGPT stuff. This is a great opportunity to build your mathematical confidence.

Comment: I did, I don't see any mistake in my calculation

Comment: Then there might be a mistake in the ChatGPT solution. Try to find it. Good luck!

Comment: I thinkt the mistake is the missing exponent: $$\frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{1}{r} \right) \neq  \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r \cdot \frac{-1}{r^2} \right)$$

Comment: Don't use chat gpt for symbolic calculations. That's not what it's designed for, and frankly, it sucks at it. Use an actual CAS (computer algebra system) like Sage, Maple, or Mathematica.

Comment: There is a singularity at origin. That is not reflected in this calculation. In the world of [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) one has $\nabla^2\frac1r = -4\pi\delta,$ where $\delta$ is the [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you should not waste your time in math with chatGPT.

Answer (score 1):

Without any calculation, you should immediately see that the ChatGPT answer must be wrong simply on dimensional grounds. Assuming that $r$ has the dimension of a length $L$, the left-hand side of your first "equation" has dimension $L^{-3}$, whereas the right-hand-side has dimension $L^{-4}$. On the other hand, the correct result $\Delta \frac{1}{r}= - 4 \pi \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x})$ is dimensionally correct as the three-dimensional delta "function" has indeed dimension $L^{-3}$.